# How to replace wildcard generic when customizing Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, generics, sonarqube, collectors

I have a Collector function that is basically toMap but always a LinkedHashMap as I need this often. Sonar complains about the ? wildcard generic in the return type. Seeing as this is the exact same signature as the toMap method, and I'm at it's mercy, how would I replace the wildcard with a proper value or generic?

I've tried `Map<K,U>` and adding an `M extends Map<K,U>` and LinkedHashMap versions of those as well, but nothing compiles.

Any suggestions?

Or is this impossible as I am using Collectors.toMap which uses a wildcard?

```
public static <T, K, U> Collector<T, ?, LinkedHashMap<K, U>> toLinkedHashMap(
        Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
        BinaryOperator<U> merger) {
    return Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, merger, LinkedHashMap::new);
}
```

Here is the full text of the Sonar rule:

Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters

## Code smell

### Major

#### squid:S1452

Using a wildcard as a return type implicitly means that the return value should be considered read-only, but without any way to enforce this contract.
Let's take the example of method returning a `List<? extends Animal>`. Is it possible on this list to add a Dog, a Cat, ... we simply don't know. The consumer of a method should not have to deal with such disruptive questions.

## Non-compliant Code Example

`List<? extends Animal> getAnimals(){...}`

Comment: And in case you are wondering why I bother, this is just the 3-param version, I have a 2-param version that's just a keyMapper and valueMapper which does reduce code a good bit.

Comment: What is the full text of the Sonar issue?

Comment: @VGR added the full-text

Comment: Wow, that is an obnoxiously cargo-cult warning.  There are all kinds of valid reasons to return a type with a wildcard bound.  You have my sympathy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* impossible as long as you use `Collections.toMap()`.

You could copy-and-paste that function (and the `mapMerger()` function on which it depends), declaring the return type as `Collector<T, LinkedHashMap<K,U>, LinkedHashMap<K,U>>`. But I think it would be better to keep your code clean and deal with Sonar. Perhaps there's a way to indicate that this is a false positive, and suppress warnings from Sonar.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I needed reassurance